# What does the $ sign mean in css and how validate it?

Tags: css, selector

in one of my css code I saw this code:

```
 .\37 u, .\37 u\24 {
            width: 58.3333333333%;
            clear: none;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
```

I try convert it ...

```
.7u, .7u$ {
            width: 58.3333333333%;
            clear: none;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
```

Now I try validate it...so I add 'i' before number....but what is '$' sign? if it is important how can I validate as a normal code?

```
.i7u, .i7u$ {
            width: 58.3333333333%;
            clear: none;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
```

I think It is just  a symble but I afraid I am wrong

Comment: To my knowledge, a dollar sign is only significant when using attribute selectors, e.g. `[data-value$="foo"]`

Comment: Where did you see the code? Any sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an invalid character to use in a class name, nothing more. CSS3 allows for UTF-8 bases characters in class names, with some exceptions:

> ~ ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) + = , . / ' ; : " ? > < [ ] \ { } | ` #
>
> [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)